# SQL to compare columns fro two different tables

Tags: php, sql, twig, silex, laragon

I am trying to use sql to only display a message if field `x` in table 1 matches field `y` in table 2

```
SELECT * 
from privatemessags 
JOIN users 
WHERE privatemessags.reciver LIKE users.id
```

That's what I currently have but it still printing both fields of my DB 
I want the message to print if `id` in table 1 is equal to the `reciver` in table 2[image: current output of SQL]

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Kinda hard to see what you are trying to do. Your question uses different table and column names than your query.. maybe `on privatemessags.id = users.reciver`. This also seems to be only a SQL question. If you don't want multiple columns replace `*` with the columns you want returned.

Comment: sorry about the confusion have been at this for a while now i want to compare the id coloumn in the users table with the recivers table in private messages table to see if they are  matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your join is incorrect. Given your statement:

*I am trying to use sql to only display a message if field x in table 1 matches field y in table 2*

Then you are indeed looking to join both tables where table1.x = table2.y. You would accomplish this by creating something similar to the following:

select message from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.x = t2.y

By joining both tables, you will only receive the messages when table1.x = table2.y.

Comment: select privatemessags.reciver from privatemessags t1 join users t2 on t1.reciver = t2.id   somting like this it doenst work but is it like what you mean

Comment: Unknown column 'privatemessags.reciver' in 'field list' is  what im getting from the above comment

Answer (score 1):

To show fields only from first table, you can specify the table name in select instruction: "privatemessags.*"

```
SELECT privatemessags.* 
from privatemessags 
JOIN users 
WHERE privatemessags.reciver LIKE users.id
```